# Bootsrap href to button not working mobile but working for desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code:

```
<a href="dashboard.php">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#5f5f5f;">
        View Summary
    </button>
</a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easy way to do that:

```
<a href="dashboard.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#5f5f5f;" role="button">View Summary</a>
```

Please look at this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

And consider adding additional class for background color in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

[You may check this Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/2fqLd9FjyG)

It's just wrapping button in anchor tags..

```
<div class="btn-group">
                <a href=href="dashboard.php"><button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
                     View Summary
                </button></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.